# How to get date difference between 24 hour format time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the time difference between 2 times. It's basically between 9 PM and 5 AM.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '21:00', '05:00')
```

Here is the query I am trying to execute but it's returning 16 hours although it should be returning 8 hours.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Your query should be returning **-16** not **16**.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the wrapping of the time to the next date.  I would recommend:

```
select (case when @start <= @end
             then datediff(hour, @start, @end)
             else 24 - datediff(hour, @end, @start)
        end) as diff_hours
```

You could also express this as:

```
select (24 + datediff(hour, @start, @end)) % 24
```

Comment: Digging the second option

Answer (score 0):

One method is with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, '21:00', '05:00') >= 0 THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, '21:00', '05:00') ELSE 24 + DATEDIFF(HOUR, '21:00', '05:00') END;
```